# Android: adding self signed certificate to CA Trusted by Browser

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have created a self signed certificate for my server which is raising (when I browse to my Web application), on my Android 2.3.4, the error `This certificate is not from a trusted authority.`

I can [read from a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device) of a couple of years ago that this was a known issue, now I'd like to understand nowadays what are my options.

Inputs:

- My device is not rooted
- I need that the certificate is accepted by the Browser and, if possible, by applications too.

How can I move on from here?