# Send HTTPS Post Request to the server

Tags: android

This is my HTTP JSON

```
 {  
 "User": {    
    "Name": "Compulsary","Password": "Compulsary"  }
}
```

Which I have to post to the server using HTTPS POST request.
When I try to send the request, I get SSL Server Certificate Exception.
How can I fix this issue ?

What I have tried ?

I have tried using `HTTPPost` with `HTTPClient`. SSL Exception.
I also tried using `URLConnection` and ignored the checking of SSL Certificates.
I am getting 401 and 405 response codes.

The Problem Statement :

Send the above POST Request to the Server (The request is secure accepts https).
How to achieve this in android ?

I have tried this, My Code, I am getting 405 error ?

```
// always verify the host - dont check for certificate
final static HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Trust every server - dont check for any certificate
 */
private static void trustAllHosts() {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
    } };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection
                .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void makeRequest() {
    URL url = null;
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://wbapi.cloudapp.net:443/api/User/LocalLogin");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        trustAllHosts();
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection
                .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(urlConnection
                .getContentLength());
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        urlConnection.connect();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonParam.put("Name", "dog");
        jsonParam.put("Password", "123");
        Log.v("Length", "" + urlConnection.getContentLength());
        int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Response" + HttpResult,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (HttpResult == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            System.out.println("ok");
            Log.v("Hi", "" + "Trex");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlConnection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();

            System.out.println("" + sb.toString());
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + sb.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            System.out.println("Here" + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Logcat entries

```
12-27 13:41:27.228: V/Length(3034): 72
12-27 13:41:27.248: I/System.out(3034): HereMethod Not Allowed
```

Comment: You should try to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device but this don't work in all cases.

Comment: I looked around a lot of stackoverflow questions, None were helpful

Comment: You need try, if none really helps you shout explain more details about your issue and should show your code

Comment: In additional could you give some log cat entries?

Comment: Getting 405 response code

Comment: Method Not Allowed is the response message I am getting

Comment: 405 response code is [HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html) and your error don't have any common with SSL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create a class `MySSLSocketFactory` and include below code:

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
                    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
                    KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super(truststore);

            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return null;
                    }
            };

            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
                    boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port,
                            autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

}
```

**Step 2:** Create a class `WebClientDevWrapper` and include the below code:

```
public class WebClientDevWrapper {

    public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
         try {
             KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
             trustStore.load(null, null);

             SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
             sf.setHostnameVerifier(
                    SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

             HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
             HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
             HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

             SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
             registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
             registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

             ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

             return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             return new DefaultHttpClient();
         }
     }

}
```

**Step 3:** Create a method inside your Activity or elsewhere, this method is going to be used for making a web call.

```
/**
     * Request JSON based web service to get response
     * 
     * @param url
     *            - base URL
     * @param request
     *            - JSON request
     * @return response
     * @throws ClientProtocolException
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    public HttpResponse request(String url, JSONObject request)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, IllegalStateException,
            JSONException {

        DefaultHttpClient client = (DefaultHttpClient) WebClientDevWrapper.getNewHttpClient();

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(request.toString(), "utf-8"));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

**Step 4:** Call a method and get response.

Comment: What is MySSLSocketFactory ?

Comment: @RajeevNB oops i forgot that, included as step-1. check

Comment: JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
  try {
   object.put("Name", "dog");
   object.put("Password", "123");
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } JSON Object for the JSON I need above ? Is it correct ?

Comment: @RajeevNB yes it seems fine.

Comment: I am getting the HTTPResponse Object. How to print its contents as String ? One more thing , I am getting response.getStatusLine() as 500/Internal Server error ?

Comment: Getting an Internal Server Error ?

Comment: @RajeevNB `response.getEntity().getContent()` gives you InputStream and do google for converting this InputStream object into String.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler solution like in iOS has it by default or a library ?

Answer (score 0):

i am using the following codes for the combination of https/http/wift/3G , hope it helps

```
public class CustomHttpClient {
private static DefaultHttpClient customHttpClient;

/** A private Constructor prevents instantiation */
private CustomHttpClient() {
}

public static synchronized DefaultHttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (customHttpClient == null) {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params,
                HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1");
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
        SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
        schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
        ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,schReg);
        customHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);
    }
    return customHttpClient;
}

public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
}
```

}

and the sample

```
public static String Call(String URL, List<NameValuePair> postParameters)
{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();   
    try{
        httpClient = CustomHttpClient.getHttpClient();

        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpClient.getParams(), false); //making 3G network works*
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```