# Android send https post request to the server without deprecated methods

Tags: android, post, ssl, https, request

In my app is used send request by https by following [this source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051304/send-https-post-request-to-the-server). Now some of them apache methods deprecated. Can anyone help me in order solve in a new approach?

Comment: You can use `HttpUrlConnection` instead of the deprecated apache methods

Comment: I need with ssl and more clear please

Comment: as you asked for detail there is a similar one here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16507195/2641726, comment if you need further assitance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid using deprecated methods in API connectivity, think about using **Retrofit**. It's a third party library which makes HTTP communication much simpler.

When using Retrofit, you can create an interface of an API endpoint and the use it like a method. The rest of the HTTP request is managed by the library.

Here is the link to the Retrofit github homepage:
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 3):

HttpURLConnection is part of SDK from API 1, you can use same http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html.

```
// HTTP POST request
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    //Your server URL
    String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    //Request Parameters you want to send
    String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);// Should be part of code only for .Net web-services else no need for PHP
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

More details you can get from

1. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/
2. http://syntx.io/how-to-send-an-http-request-from-android-using-httpurlconnection/

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below function:

```
  public String makeServiceCall(String url1, MultipartEntity reqEntity) {
    try {
        // http client
        URL url= new URL(url1);
        HttpURLConnection httpClient = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpClient.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpClient.setUseCaches(false);
        httpClient.setDoInput(true);
        httpClient.setDoOutput(true);
        httpClient.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        httpClient.addRequestProperty("Content-length", reqEntity.getContentLength()+"");


         OutputStream os = httpClient.getOutputStream();
         reqEntity.writeTo(httpClient.getOutputStream());
         os.close();
         httpClient.connect();

         if (httpClient.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
             return readStream(httpClient.getInputStream());
         }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android SDK 23

`HttpClient` is deprecated, you can migrate your code in `HttpURLConnection`

Something like this

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want to continue using HttpClient for API level 22 and 23.. 
add **org.apache.http.legacy.jar** in ur project's **Lib** folder,
ull get **.jar** file in **Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional..**

if ur using android studio, after copy pasting jar file in lib folder,right click on jar file and click **add as library**

ur problem will be solved..comment if need any help.
thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this Method for Get or Post Any purpose. Just use this method for Server request.

```
public void RequestToServer() {
        //  String User_id = "h";
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        // params.put("uid", User_id.toString());
        client.post("http:// Your Url", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                super.onSuccess(s);
                Log.d("Server Response for success :", s);
                tv.append("service_ReloadSqlDB" + "    " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(throwable);
                Log.d("Server Response for onFailure ", throwable.toString());
            }
        });

    }
```

You also need a jar file = android-async-http-1.3.1.jar 
download this jar and add your android project in libs folder 
 After that  add this in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {

compile files('libs/<android-async-http-1.3.1.jar>')
}
```

Finally rebuild your project , run the application , Get your Server response.