# install SSL certificate in android device for SSO

Tags: android, ssl

I have to intall a SSL certificate in android device, so that it can be accessed from each browser and other application for Single Sign ON (SSO).
**I can not go for Root access**. Is there another way ?
I just need to ensure is it possible  that I can install the SSL certificate in somewhere around (in certificate store / common place) of android device. Which can be used for SSO by other applications and browser.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of ways. Some more complicated than others. Here are some links:

- http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2013/03/16/manually-install-ssl-certificate-in-android-jelly-bean/
- [How to install trusted CA certificate on Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device)
- [Accepting a certificate for HTTPs on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android)

Comment: Hi Anup , I am new to android, Do you propose to use the keystore here. Also , In the first link "Work with certificates " page is not available.

Comment: The keystore method would be the easiest if you want to accept only your cert. Usually, in debugging, I enable all certs from any provider (basically by-passing HTTPS) and I enable it back in production.

Comment: No, I want to accept all the other cert in browser, with my cert. Hence, as you suggested ,keystore will not work. I have gone through the links , but every where the root access was needed. I want to make sure that the SSO will work and certificate will be available without root acces to my application and other browsers on device.

Comment: You cannot modify the browser so that it accepts all SSL certs. You can only modify the certs accepted by your own app.

Comment: Okey, Also I need to mention, that there are n number of application which will need this certificate. So is there another way that, my all the applications cab access this certificate. Since Keystore will be a solution for one application and not a generic solution. Can you please provide me more information regarding the issue.

Comment: You have two options: (1) Bypass HTTPS on all debug versions and enable in production or (2) Create a keystore as mentioned in the last link and use the same keystore for all your apps.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be not possible on android .
I found an issue registered for the same 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53491

Native app, can not access the certificate stored in keystore not even through webview.