# Is credentials in Android Trusted Credentials in all devices?

Tags: android, ssl, https

I am using SSL from StartCom.

I see that in Android Trusted Credentials, StartCom is one of them.

However, does every Android device include the same trusted credentials??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can get their SSL certificates validated from well-known certificate authorities (CA). Root Certificates from these authorities are included in Android. If StartCom's certificate is verified by one of these CA's, it will be trusted. [You can also add your own certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device) manually.

More info:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/x64.html