# Connection to https://api.parse.com refused

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an application which has a login screen, there are two options, 1 login with twitter and 2. username and password.

This application is live on the store, however, I am currently getting some reports of connection being refused to api.parse.com.  I have tested here on multiple devices and it's connecting fine.

Are there any reasons that parse may refuse connection other than there being an issue with their servers?  Could device imei etc come into play?  I just find this unusual that it's happening for some and not others.  Plus, I'll end up losing a lot of users in this way.

Any guidance is appreciated.

***I'd really appreciate any help on this if anyone knows anything about it, parse.com status says it's fully operational, there's no parse forum any more, if someone could give me some insight it would be great***

Comment: I believe that you can get problems like that if you exceed the free tear. I'd suggest to check your dashboard.

Comment: I had thought that myself and I have checked it but we're no where near limits..

Comment: Then please elaborate on what "connection refused" means. Some stack traces would be useful.

Comment: this is the problem, it's not a crash and it's not happening on our devices so I don't have any stack traces..I received an email with the error : i/of failure: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectExectption: Connection to https://api.parse.com refused

Comment: I'd suggest to ask on Parse forums.

Comment: there isn't a parse forum anymore just archives...it's suggest you move your question here and add parse.com tag

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out as a possibility, this maybe a SSL issue since your are connecting to `https://` endpoint.

The built in trusted root certificates vary from phone to phone, so the connection could be failing because the certificate is missing.

In that case you maybe able to [install a root trusted certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device).

---

Here is a relevant link about the certificate used by parse.com, **DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA** :

- [This cross signed certificate maybe missing at Parse.com.](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170606-Why-am-I-receiving-a-warning-about-my-high-assurance-Digicert-SSL-certificate-having-outdated-intermediate-certificates-)

Comment: thank you for you reply, I sincerely hope that's not the issue as it might cause serious issues down the line with a lot more users

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if your answer is the cause for this but it has come to our attention that the user's phone that this occurs on is rooted which may indeed have an impact on security certificates etc..

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue and it boils down to an ad blocker called AdFree. Ask the users having this issue, if they have the said ad blocker and to disable it and try.