# Why does Android 2.2 throws security warning where as Android 4.2 won't?

Tags: android, webview, ssl-certificate, webviewclient

Recently I was working on loading url in WebView, the url loads fine without any issue on Android 4.2 but when I run the same code on android 2.2 it throws error, to track the error I override the method in my `WebViewClient`

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                SslError error) {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            handler.proceed();
        }
```

To check if there is issue in my code, I pasted same url in Android 4.2 browser, worked fine but when I paste it in android 2.2 browser it shows error dialogue ( See the image ), any help appreciated[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different Android versions include different [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) certificates. Android 4.2 included [100 CA certificates](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#Concepts) but probably Android 2.2 did not include the one valid for the URL you are visiting.

You can verify the list of trusted certificates in your phone settings.

Comment: Can I check for the required certificate and tell user to install it?

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device)
I don't think it will be easy to ask users to install a new certificate, though.