# Installing a certificate with my app

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I need to install a ssl-certificate when users install my application to access a dedicated https server.
Is it possible and how to do please?

Regards

Comment: Why do you think that you need to "install" a certificate on the device, rather than just *use* the certificate yourself in your app's SSL communications?

Comment: I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device). I hope it may help you.

Comment: @user1753641 thanks, I didn't see this thread.