# Certificate trust issue on Skype for business App sdk

Tags: skype-for-business

When I am accessing a meeting URI using the GuestmeetingJoin sample app, I am getting the following error.

SfbCertificateTrustEngine: Certificate NOT trusted by the standard OS trust manager: X509CertificateInfo

How can I make the library to trust the certificate. What makes the app sdk to trust our certificate. The certificate issued by our CA is not leading to a publicly trusted entity. But we want to try it for Proof of concept for now. I am trying this on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a programing problem but a device setup problem.

The device but have the root certificate (and intermediate certificates) installed into the devices trusted root certificates list.

If your sfb uses a self-signed certificate (which will be my guess) then you need to get and install this self-signed certificate onto the device.  How this is done may be different for different devices (PC, Mac, IPhone, IPad, Andriod, etc).  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device) on how to install a certificate onto a android device.

Comment: Thanks Shane. You are right. I installed the certificate on the device and then started to move. I am now debugging why the Audio and Video are both not working.