# android: do the keys in the keystore vary in different devices?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm planning to use the android keystore system. I will use a function close to this

```
public void createNewKeys(View view) {
    String alias = aliasText.getText().toString();
    try {
        // Create new key if needed
        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
            Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
            end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
            KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(this)
                    .setAlias(alias)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=Sample Name, O=Android Authority"))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                    .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                    .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                    .build();
            KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
            generator.initialize(spec);

            KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception " + e.getMessage() + " occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    refreshKeys();
}
```

my question is, when i generate a key while building the app, is it going to be retrievable when the app is installed on a different devices?

Comment: Starting from version 4.0 you can, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device