# Android 7.0/Self-signed certificate: "Trust anchor for certification path not found"

Tags: android, https, x509certificate, self-signed

My app accesses a URL that is secured with a self-signed certificate.

**Version 1**:

I copied the "selfsigned.crt" file onto the phone, then installed the certificate through `Security - Other Security Settings - Install from device storage` with `credential use: VPN and apps`, which also made me set a PIN.

Afterwards I added this to the manifest:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

... and created the according `network_security_config.xml` file in the "res/xml" folder (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040887/2016165)):

```
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

The problem is that my app can't connect to the URL like this and only throws an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

**Version 2**:

If I copy the "selfsigned.crt" file into the "res/raw" folder and add this to the xml file:

```
<certificates src="@raw/selfsigned"/>
```

it succeeds. But this also means that I'd have to update the app if the certificate changes.

**Question:**

Did I miss anything in version 1, do you maybe have to create your own `KeyStore`/`TrustManager` (as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#SelfSigned)), even when you're using the xml file?

Btw, currently I'm using `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` instead of the "basic" `URLConnection` to open a connection.