# How to fix SSL handshake aborted Android 5.1?

Tags: java, android, ssl, tls1.2, okhttp

I am trying to connect via an Android 5.1 device using the `Okhttp` library to a server with *TLS 1.2 encryption*. When trying to connect:

> SSL handshake aborted error occurs: ssl = 0xaXXXXXXXX: I / O error during system call, Connection reset by peer.

I was looking for a solution to the problem on the Internet, but the problem is that *Google Play services* **are not** installed on my target devices.

How can this problem be solved?

This code is checked and working on devices android 7-9 with Google Play services

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "https://domen/app/rest/v2/oauth/token";
    String credential = Credentials.basic("username", "password");
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("grant_type", "password")
            .addFormDataPart("username", login)
            .addFormDataPart("password", password)
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .post(requestBody)
            .header("Authorization", credential)
            .url(url)
            .build();
```

Comment: Share some code for better understanding.

Comment: you don't have to change anything in app. check your domain have proper chain certificate or not.https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
 Don't west your time to fix from app side. its totally issue with back-end.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel , ssl certificate verification is successful

Comment: Does your android application (or your client) TRUST the CA which issued the certificate to your server having TLS enabled? This is the basic requirement.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo How to make the client trust the certificate authority? In the case of Android 9, the connection is successful.

Comment: @Dot it would require importing the CA's certificate in the client's trust store / trusted CA authorities list

Comment: Probably this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo Is it possible to bypass certificate verification?

Comment: @Dot I wouldn't recommend doing that. It should be easy to import the root CA certificate into your client's Trusted Root CA authorities. This is very basic thing to do, and once it is done, your application should work over TLS.