# Android: how to create root CA certificate

Tags: android, certificate, root, auto-update, ca

Can somebody explain what is exactly the root CA certificate in Android? Can I create it by myself? If I create a root CA certificate and install it on an android device, then I can update my custom application on this device **SILENTLY**?

Comment: Visit this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device

Comment: I saw it earlier, but it doesn't answer on all my questions.

Comment: @Rougher you can create the certificate but you will not be able to update the app silently.