# Performance testing of hybrid app (jmeter)

Tags: performance, jmeter, hybrid-mobile-app

Can we test hybrid app through jmeter and if yes then how
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use JMeter for load testing mobile apps **themselves**, if you need to check i.e. application loading time, page rendering time, resources consumption (CPU, RAM, Network, Battery), etc. you should rather consider using profiling tools, they're normally available from mobile operating system vendors like:

- iOS: [Xcode Instruments usage to improve app performance](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/xcode-instruments-time-profiler/)
- Android: [Measure app performance with Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)

---

JMeter can be used in context of measuring mobile applications performance only if the application communicates with the [**backend**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end) so you can simulate hundreds/thousands of mobile application users using JMeter so you can check whether the backend is capable of handling such a load and it doesn't result in increased response time or errors. If this is what you're trying to achieve - you need to determine which [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) are in scope and check if these protocols are supported by JMeter [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

If your mobile app uses [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol for communicating with the backend you can even record the requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), see [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) article for example concept.

If your application uses [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol it is still possible to record the traffic however you will have to take some extra steps:

1. Install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto the mobile device (see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for explanation)
2. Configure your mobile operating system to trust this certificate:

   - iOS: [Trust manually installed certificate profiles in iOS and iPadOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477)
   - Android: [How to install trusted CA certificate on Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040887/2897748%5C)