# Fiddler: This certificate isn't from a trusted authority

Tags: android, fiddler

My `Fiddler certificate` not working correctly in `Android` Device and show me the error.

I install and reset it Certificates from fiddler in my pc.

set it the correct proxy in my Android device

Install it certificate  from link `http://ipv4.fiddler:8888/`

I monitoring `HTTP` requests but `HTTPS` request get it the error:

> This certificate isn't from a trusted authority

Comment: see docs: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/troubleshooting/untrustedcertwarnings ?

Comment: i use it this step too. my problem in android device.

Comment: you have to make sure the android device does trust that certificate too. ? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device   or    https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+an+android+device+trust+a+certificate+site%3Astackoverflow.com )